# Flutter place filter based on variable in firestore request

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am working on an app which requests based on the registered Userid certain elements from my firestore.

Now i'm trying to build the Notifier related to this but somehow it breaks when putting the filter in the firestore request

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:tutora/states/question_notifier.dart';
import 'package:tutora/models/answers.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

Future<String> id() async {
  FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
  String userID = user.uid.toString();
  return userID;
}

getAnswers(AnswerNotifier answerNotifier) async {
  QuerySnapshot snapshot = await Firestore.instance
      .collection('Questions')
      .where(
        'UserID',
        isEqualTo: await id(),
      )
      .getDocuments();

  List<Answer> _answerList = [];

  snapshot.documents.forEach((document) {
    Answer answer = Answer.fromMap(document.data);
    _answerList.add(answer);
  });
  answerNotifier.answerList = _answerList;
}
```

What in my head this should do is that it gets the current user ID and then based on that ones only collects the Questions which match on the column UserID.

This works perfectly fine if i manually enter the UserID in my code however the moment where it requests the current user ID from id() it does not find any matching questions. So my question list in the app is empty as well as ofc my _answerList here.

The user is logged in at this point in the app where this Answernotifier is called.

Thankful for any help this is really bugging me now quit some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
getAnswers(AnswerNotifier answerNotifier) async {
  String userId = await id();
  QuerySnapshot snapshot = await Firestore.instance
      .collection('Questions')
      .where('UserID',isEqualTo: userId).getDocuments();
```

get the `userId` first and then use the result inside the `where()` query.